# How to access a file with a js console?

Tags: javascript, jssh

I have downloaded the windows version of the js shell from here http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-trunk/. Now if i want to run a js script and for example the file is in the "F:\projects" directory,how can i run the file?I have read the doc but didn't really understand it.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell):

```
F:
cd projects
js the_file.js
```